# reconcile git divergent branches with same commit message

Tags: git, git-lfs

a migration to a new git remote went wrong; git-lfs was removed for some branches but not all. We have functionally similar branches that have diverged at the root.
That is

Branch 1
A-B-C-D-E-F

Branch 2
*A'-B'-C'*-X-Y-Z

where *prime(')* commits are the same except for lfs and the hash of their parent. Note that there are about 60000 commits, and development continued for some time in Branch 1.

The Task is now to get commits X-Y-Z over to Branch 1, resulting in A-B-C-D-E-F-X-Y-Z

a naive first try with git-merge failed for the sheer number of conflicts. git cherry-pick could work, but we are not sure if we can identify all relevant commits.

is there a better approach?

maybe a strategy or a merge driver?

Comment: I don't get why cherry-pick would not work? If the last N commits are to be picked, they should be fairly easy to identify?

Comment: i simplified a bit, but it's not just the last n commits. They are interspersed with other commits, and not all have a JIRA id as an identifer

Answer (score 1):

> The Task is now to merge commits X-Y-Z over to Branch 1.

So you want to end up with

Branch 1 `A-B-C-D-E-F-X-Y-Z`, right?

Then that is a straight forward rebase using the `--onto` argument:

```bash
git branch Branch_2.tmp Branch_2           # Keep Branch_2 as is (for now at least)
git rebase --onto Branch_1 C' Branch_2.tmp # Rebase commits from (NOT including) C'
                                           # to (including) the head of (old)
                                           # Branch_2.tmp on top of Branch_1 and
                                           # then let (new) Branch_1.tmp point to
                                           # the result.
git checkout Branch_1
git merge --ff Branch_1.tmp
git branch -d Branch_1.tmp
```

Comment: looks good. i will accept the answer as soon as i have tested this.

Comment: @AndreasFrische have you tested it already?